# Altium - Changing the libraries for completed schematics and PCB design

Tags: altium, library

I made a design using a library (say 'All.SchLib' and 'All.PcbLib' where I have everything). Then I made libraries from the project (say 'projectA.Schlib' and 'projectA.Pcblib' which now contain only the parts from the project).

Can I change the libraries in the project from 'All.SchLib' and 'All.PcbLib' to 'projectA.Schlib' and 'projectA.Pcblib' so that 'All' is removed from the project?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove All.SchLib and All.PcbLib from your project any time you want without affecting the schematics or layout files. Even if you haven't created the ProjectA.Schlib and ProjectA.Pcblib files first.

You could even do that and then rebuild the parts of the libraries you used with the "make library from design" commands afterwards.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I created the libraries and removed the old one. Now still the components are pointing to the old library. I need to select each component and change the library to the new one in both schematics and PCB.

Comment: You can probably use "Find similar objects" to do that with minimal effort.